# in-app purchase not working in playstore, which previously worked in market

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have a problem with in-app billing.when i connect to google play it shows a message that

> The Market billing
>        service is not available at this time.  You can continue to use this app but you
>        won\'t be able to make purchases.

But earlier i was able to connect with market and make purchases.But that time it was android market instead of google play store.Can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Finally i  got the answer.

> While calling the billingservice i had to use getApplicationContext.bindservice() instead of this.bindservice().Because my activity comes under a tabhost, which doesn't accept the context "this"..

Also refer this link [billing-not-supported-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353969/android-cannot-bind-to-service-in-app-billing)